# Resources to accompany First Course in Probability by Sheldon Ross

Tags: probability, combinatorics, probability-theory, statistics, online-resources

#### Probability Resources

I am taking a probability course this semester and we are using **(First Course in Probability by Sheldon Ross 9th edition)** textbook.
Unfortunately I can't understand from my professor, he is just reading from the book.
Also the book isn't explaining much especially for a first-year computer science student, not a pure mathematician.
The problems are very hard and I can't solve much of them I just finished the mid-term and it was painful.
 So if you know any good resource (lectures) that goes with this textbook it would be very helpful.
I tried sat 101 (Harvard University) but it was different from my book and not helpful with the problems.

Comment: I would suggest asking students taking the same course what resources they found most useful-students in the second and third years should be able to assist you.

Comment: The book title you cite is very common for intro probability texts. Please supply the author's name.

Comment: "derives me crazy" --- just wait until density functions..!

Comment: The book title is First Course in Probability by Sheldon Ross 9th edition. @coffeemath

Comment: @John_dydx I asked a lot of students in my class and from other classes too their advice was the professor puts his exams from this reference and this reference has a solution book just memorize the solution of the problem even if you can't get it.

Comment: A start would be to take one thing that you do not understand and formalize your question about it.

Comment: Ross also has a text "Introduction to Probability Models" which is less theoretical and definitely more suited for one with no prior background in probability or real analysis.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this professor who goes through the book and he explains everything in a good way.
[Playlist](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AUT-ky6e8Oc&list=PLUTn30k919O_dwIAqUqq37gNQJFHCDQ2D)